# Understanding Java Exception Handling: Simple Try Catch blocks

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to learn Java Exception handling.  I wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem1
{
    static Scanner length = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            double x;
            double y;

            System.out.println("Input a length in Feet and than Inches.");

            x = length.nextDouble();
            y = length.nextDouble();

            try
            {
                    System.out.println("Feet - Inches:" + x * 12);
                    System.out.println("Inches - Centimeters:" + y * 2.14);
            }

            catch (InputMismatchException imeRef)
            {
                    System.out.println("Do not use letters" + imeRef.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

The program simply converts inputs in Feet and Inches to just Inches.  I try to break it by giving it an input of:

```
-1
e
```

The program breaks but I'm not properly catching and handling the exception.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You want to catch any exception when converting the user input into double. And that happens in the following line of code:
`x = length.nextDouble();`
`y = length.nextDouble();`

Hence these two line should have been inside the try statement

Comment: Yes!  I've been staring at this so long and missed the obvious.  Thank you!

Comment: please up-vote if comment was useful. Thanks

Comment: Your answer doesn't allow me to upvote for some reason.

Comment: I also need to get it so that it does not allow an input of negative numbers, I'm not sure what type of exceptions I would have to use in another catch statement.

Comment: Do you really need to throw an exception if the number are negative?
Because you can use simple if statement to check if the number is negative or not and do appropriate thing. `if (x<0)`  - you then do something, like output on the console

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the 2 input statements which read the input from the user into the `try` block. The error will be thrown only when the input is read and to handle that in the catch, these statements need to be in the `try` block because the catch will handle only the exceptions thrown in its corresponding `try` block.

```
try {
    x = length.nextDouble(); // moved inside try
    y = length.nextDouble(); // moved inside try
    System.out.println("Feet - Inches:" + x * 12);
    System.out.println("Inches - Centimeters:" + y * 2.14);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following two lines -

```
 x = length.nextDouble();
 y = length.nextDouble();
```

inside your `try` block -

```
try {
    x = length.nextDouble();
    y = length.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Feet - Inches:" + x * 12);
    System.out.println("Inches - Centimeters:" + y * 2.14);
}
catch (InputMismatchException imeRef) {
    System.out.println("Do not use letters" + imeRef.toString());
}
```

A `catch` block only catches the matching exceptions thrown by the statements ***inside*** of its corresponding `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

You do not catch exception is because the exception is thrown when calling length.nextDouble() for variable x and y.

```
  x = length.nextDouble();
  y = length.nextDouble();
```

But You do not put them in try - catch code. Put the above 2 line code to try - catch,  you will catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

A catch statement only catches exceptions that are thrown in its corresponding try block.

This is what you want. This prompts the user for each question, one at a time, and resets and asks again on bad input. Note the length.next() in the catch - that's needed to avoid an infinite loop - you have to advance past that bad token.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Input a length in feet");
        double x = length.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input a length in inches");
        double y = length.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Feet - Inches:" + x * 12);
        System.out.println("Inches - Centimeters:" + y * 2.14);

        break;
    }

    catch (InputMismatchException imeRef) {
        System.out.println("Do not use letters" + imeRef.toString());

        // need to purge the bad token
        length.next();
    }
}
```